# Can't change NSButton's width permanently with auto layout enabled in xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I changed the size of a NSButton when I clicked on it. But it's size is restored to default when I resize the window. I realised it's because of the Auto Layout option.

So, the question is, can't I change position or size of a control permanently with auto layout option enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an outlet:

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonWidthConstraint;
```

Go to NIB. Select your button and pin it's width (Editor - Pin - Width). This will add width constraint into button constraints. Connect newly created constraint to outlet above.

And in button click event:

```
- (IBAction)buttonDidClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.buttonWidthConstraint setConstant:300]; // set new width
}
```

upd: The idea behind this is that auto layout engine overwrites view frames each time it is needed, so manual changes like [view setFrame:] do not apply. So the only way to change some properties of layout is to work on layout level instead. Layout constraint is just a formula like:

```
item1.attr1 {== | <= | >=} multiplier * {item2.attr2 | none} + constant
```

In your case, this constraint is as simple as `MyButton.width = 1 * (none) + 70`, where 70 is original width suggested by Xcode.